# c# - How to arrange elements in WindowsForm like Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, dock

I'm populating a self-made Windows Explorer which simulate the Microsoft Windows Explorer. This is the layout of my Windows Form:
[image]

What I want it to be is: 
[image]

But when I maximized the windows, it looks like this:

[image]

**The problem is that the treeView's width got increased, too. How to stop that ?**

Any ideas? I've tried many ways but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a second `splitcontainer` around the `groupbox` and the `splitcontainer` you already have. Then set the `panel` at the bottom as the fixed panel.

Comment: how to add a vertical splitContainer, because it is horizontal with 2 columns by default ?

Comment: THANK MATE ! I've solved the groupbox problem but the treeView is not ... Could you help me again ?

Comment: You can change the Orientation in the properties.  I believe the number of panels are fixed, but you could put another split container inside one panel.

Comment: THANK MATE ! I've solved the groupbox problem but the treeView is not ... Could you help me again

Comment: What problem do you encounter with the treeview?

Comment: When I maximized the window form, the width of TreeView got increased too (But I just want the list view got bigger) ... how to stop that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`SplitContainer.FixedPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.fixedpanel.aspx) property to disable automatic resizing of one of the panels. This way the specified panel will remain the same width/height even when the container itself is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Anchoring (each control will have that in the Properties menu), and select what you want it "anchored" to.  That should allow your controls to stetch to fit the form.

It can be fiddly, so you have to anchor each control and think about how to wish to set it.  EG to make a control extend if you increase the height of your form, click the top and bottom anchors.